# Yeoman - Angular Material partial html template are not correctly loaded after grunt build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, angular-material, mddialog

I've made an Angular Material web application using Yeoman as project starter. When I run

```
grunt serve
```

I can see the website in localhost correctly and everything is working.
When I run:

```
grunt build
```

to build my web application, it finishes without any errors.
After that, I upload the dist folder content to my online web server, but when I navigate to the web application, the partial template html I used in $mddialog are not loaded and i get this error:

```
GET http://my.website.url/views/dialogs/dialoginfodocument.html 404 (Not Found)
on file vendor.t3fefw.js
```

The $mddialog code is:

```
          $mdDialog.show({
            scope: $scope,
            templateUrl: './views/dialogs/dialoginfodocument.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: $event,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            preserveScope:true,
            useFullScreen: useFullScreen
          })
```

and the partial template html:

```
<md-dialog>  
<md-toolbar>.....</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content>....</md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try removing leading `./`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) comment I solved the issue.
The problem was the leading `./` before html template url.